# icefaces fileEntry

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I am using ace:fileEntry and have 2 problems:

1. I am trying to change the style so the area of the input file (where the file name is presented) will be bigger. How can I do that?
2. My component is working okay but there is an error message on the component fileEntryListener, why?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to change the size .

Icefaces forgot to add 'size' attribute to ace:fileEntry component ,

so we must insert it by using javaScript .

```
function openFilePanel() 
{
     // find the component in the document
     var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
     for(var i=0 ; i< nodeList.length;i++)
     {
         var  item =  nodeList[i];
         if(item.getAttribute("type") == "file") 
         { //  create and set the 'size' attribute  
             item.setAttribute("size", "70");
            }
        }

}
```

if you are using more then one ace:fileEntry component you must find the 'input' that it create differently.